# How to get tornado object?

Tags: python, object, tornado, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to get value of a tornado object with key

This is my code :

```
beanstalk = beanstalkt.Client(host='host', port=port)
beanstalk.connect()
print("ok1")

beanstalk.watch('contracts')
stateTube = beanstalk.stats_tube('contracts', callback=show)
print("ok2")

ioloop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
ioloop.start()

print("ok3")
```

And this is the function `show()``

```
def show(s):
    pprint(s['current-jobs-ready'])
    ioloop.stop
```

When I look at the documentation I found this : 
[image]

And when I excecute this code, I have this :

```
ok1
ok2
3
```

In fact I have the result I wanted "3" but I don't understand why my program continue to running? Whythe ioloop doesn't close? I don't have `ok3`when I compile how can I do to close the ioloop and have `ok3`?

Comment: You have a `Future` object. Please show the tornado code that you've tried to call this

Comment: @cricket_007, I've update my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`beanstalk.stats_tube` is async, it returns a `Future` which represents a future result that has not yet been resolved.

As [the README says](https://github.com/nephics/beanstalkt), Your callback `show` will be executed with a dict that contains the resolved result. So you could define `show` like:

```
def show(stateTube):
    pprint(stateTube['current-job-ready'])

beanstalk.stats_tube('contracts', callback=show)

from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
IOLoop.current().start()
```

Note that you pass `show`, not `show()`: you're passing the function itself, not calling the function and passing its return value.

The other way to resolve a Future, besides passing a callback, is to use it in a coroutine:

```
from tornado import gen
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

@gen.coroutine
def get_stats():
    stateTube = yield beanstalk.stats_tube('contracts')
    pprint(stateTube['current-job-ready'])

loop = IOLoop.current()
loop.spawn_callback(get_stats)
loop.start()
```

Comment: I've edit my post. I tryed to do the first method but I've some problem ...

Comment: It's ok I find the solution! Thanks a lot !

Comment: I post a new question concerning exception into callback : [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39974225/tornado-how-to-return-error-exception) can you help me please?