# Tornado how to return error exception?

Tags: python, exception, tornado, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to run a method I know this method doesn't work and I want to get the error returned by the method.

This is my code :

```
def is_connect(s):
    print("ok connection")
    print(s)
    ioloop.stop()


try:


    current_job_ready = 0
    print("ok1")
    beanstalk = beanstalkt.Client(host='host', port=port)

    print("ok1")
    beanstalk.connect(callback=is_connect)


    ioloop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
    ioloop.start()
    print("ok2")
except IOError as e:
    print(e)
```

And this is the error I have when I run my program with wring port :

```
WARNING:tornado.general:Connect error on fd 7: ECONNREFUSED
ERROR:tornado.application:Exception in callback <functools.partial object at 0x7f5a0eac6f18>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 604, in _run_callback
    ret = callback()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 275, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 619, in <lambda>
    self.add_future(ret, lambda f: f.result())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 237, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 270, in wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: connect() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

I want to have e when I enter a false port or host. 
How can I do this? 
I tired to add `raise IOError("connection error")` after `beanstalk = beanstalkt.Client(host='host', port=port)` But this force the error, and I just want to have error when it exist.

Comment: Could you post full code?

Comment: @Simon, The rest of my code not concern by this part.

Comment: Alright. The part then? Missing full statement.

Comment: @Simon, I've updeta my code

Comment: Weren't you encountering a a TypeError?

Comment: @Simon, I've update my code, I add the error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125419/discussion-between-wxcvbn-and-simon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's where reading the code helps. In beanstalkt 0.6's `connect`, it creates an IOStream to connect to the server:

https://github.com/nephics/beanstalkt/blob/v0.6.0/beanstalkt/beanstalkt.py#L108

It registers your callback to be executed on success, but if the connection fails it'll just call `Client._reconnect` once per second forever. I think you should open a feature request in their GitHub project asking for an error-notification system for `connect`. With the current beanstalkt implementation, you just have to decide how long you're willing to wait for success:

```
import sys
from datetime import timedelta

from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

def is_connect(s):
    print("ok connection")
    print(s)
    loop.remove_timeout(timeout)
    # Do something with Beanstalkd....

def connection_failed():
    print(sys.stderr, "Connection failed!")
    # Could call IOLoop.stop() or just quit.
    sys.exit(1)

loop = IOLoop.current()
timeout = loop.add_timeout(timedelta(seconds=1), connection_failed)
beanstalk.connect(callback=is_connect)
loop.start()
```

Comment: @A. Jesse Jiryu Davis Hey, could you help me for this problem please ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40629057/run-worker-beanstalkt-tornado-in-docker-container